# System.ArgumentException: "Недопустимый параметр." в bitmap

Tags: c#, графика, bitmap

есть код на запись екрана в файл. После нажатия button1 программа работает 20 секунд, и выключается с ошибкой System.ArgumentException: "Недопустимый параметр." на этой bp = new Bitmap(1920, 1080); или на этой gr.CopyFromScreen(0, 0, 0, 0, bp.Size); строчке, в чем может быть проблема?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Accord.Video.FFMPEG;

namespace Screen
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        Bitmap bp;
        Graphics gr;
        VideoFileWriter vf;
        string path = @"C:\Users\gmoss\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\video.avi";
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            vf = new VideoFileWriter();
            vf.Open(path, 1920, 1080, 24, VideoCodec.MPEG4, 100000000);
            timer1.Start();
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            timer1.Stop();
            vf.Close();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            timer1 = new Timer();
            timer1.Interval = 24;
            timer1.Tick += timer1_Tick;
        }

        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            bp = new Bitmap(1920, 1080);
            gr = Graphics.FromImage(bp);
            gr.CopyFromScreen(0, 0, 0, 0, bp.Size);
            pictureBox1.Image = bp;
            vf.WriteVideoFrame(bp);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Текст ошибки бы узнать. Какой именно параметр там недопустимый?

Comment: `timer1.Interval = 24;` это что значит? раз в 24 миллисекунды в делаете скриншот? Но ведь `Компонент таймера Windows Forms является однопотоковым и ограничивается точностью до 55 миллисекунд.` - [ссылка](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.timer?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: @aepot, просто пишет исключение не отработало, и данную ошибку. А таймер да, так получается запись в 24 кадра.

Comment: Вы не поняли, что совершили сразу 2 ошибки? Первое: задержка в 24 миллисекунды - это 41,6 кадров в секунду. Посчитайте математически: сколько интервалов по 24 миллисекунды уместится в 1 секунде? Второе: точность таймера 55 мс, это значит что установка интервала меньше, чем 55мс не имеет никакого смысла, что разрешает вам иметь максимальную частоту кадров - 18 кадров в секунду (в лучшем случае). Если вы хотите 24, `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` вам не подходит, совсем. Теоретически подойдет `System.Threading.Timer`, его точность ~1мс.

Comment: @aepot Просто проблема в том, что если я сделаю интервал 10, то исключение не пропадет.

Comment: 10мс - это 100 кадров в секунду. От чего исключение у вас возникает - я без понятия, я указываю вам на ошибки, которые вижу.